# Fade a function out from another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I have a function that is fading in and out of four boxes that are in a row and then it loops through again and again. Box 1 fades in and out, then box 2, then box 3, and finally box 4. This is done in one function.

I have another function that when a user hovers over the heading of one of these boxes that box will fade in. Then when they hover off it fades out. What I want to do in that function is when they hover on one of the headings over the box, the function controlling the looping (startSlider) will fade out, then when they hover off the heading the looping begins again.

Here is some code:

```
function startSlider(){
    //code that is looping through each box is here
};

function hoverHere(){
    $('.headings .b1').on("mouseenter", function(){
        $('.box #1').fadeIn(300);
        //startslider() fade out this function
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function(){
        $('.box #1').fadeOut(300);
        //startslider() begins again
    });

    //there is the same code here for .b2 and .box #2 and so on
}
```

Thanks for any help on how to stop this function from looping when hover is in effect and then to start the startSlider() function when hover is off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put everything in one function so all the variables will be
in scope.. also I'm using .index() which gives you the index of the element
in regards to its parent (a simpler way of connecting between the boxes clicked and the infoboxes affected.
To make the loop start right away, I've separated the actual sliding function from the looping interval, so you can call the function separately in the beginning and then start the loop.. Notice you only need to call startSlider() function in doc ready. Let me know if you have any issues.. If you rather do it the other way and only want the loop function to start immediately than you can just separate the sliding function as in the example.

```
function startSlider(){

    // timer
    var loop = 0;

    // get total boxes
    var count=$('.box .info').length; 

    // slide index
    var sliderIndex = 0;

    // boxes
    var boxes = $(".headings").children("div");

    // info boxes
    var infoboxes = $("#main_cont").find(".info");

    // bind boxes hover
    boxes.off().on('mouseenter', handlehover);

    function resetSlider() {
        window.clearInterval(loop);
        loop=window.setInterval(moveSlider, 2000);
    }
    function moveSlider() {
        if(sliderIndex+1 == count){  //will reset to first image when last image fades out
            sliderIndex = 0;
        }
        infoboxes.fadeOut(400);
        infoboxes.eq(sliderIndex).fadeIn(400); // slider image + the next image in the slider

        sliderIndex++;
    }

    function handlehover() {
        var boxnum = $(this).index();

        boxes.off().on('mouseleave', resetSlider);
        pauseSlider();
    }

    function pauseSlider() {
        window.clearInterval(loop);
        infoboxes.not(":eq("+boxnum+")").fadeOut(400);
        infoboxes.eq(boxnum).fadeIn(400);

    }
}

$(function() {
    startSlider();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately the loop does not run if I add that timer = setInterval part in it. If you would be willing to look at the source go to chaselester.com/mwa. It doesn't have the hoverHere() function there yet, but you can see the startSlider function

Comment: sure :) i'm looking at your function, firstly I noticed you're using .size(), I'm pretty sure it might be deprecated so you should probably just use .length instead just to be sure...to clarify, you're loop is currently working and all you want to do is stop the loop when hovering on either box right?

Comment: Yes, when the first header box is hovered, then the box under it will fade in and the loop will stop and fade out until the header box is hovered off, then loop will fade back in, and can start over

Comment: I took the code from your site and edited above.. let me know if that works for ya.

Comment: Almost.. to get this working, I've taken pauseSlider out of the callback function, and call hoverHere() inside of startSlider().. try the edited code above, should work as expected.

Comment: Hi Chipe, it seems to be working, can you specify what isn't right yet?

Comment: Every thing seems to be working except when I hover over one of the four header boxes. The loop fades out, but the header I hover on there is no fade in of the content in the box below. When I hover off, the loop starts again. I just dont have the content fading in below the box I hover on.

Comment: if you want the info for that box to appear just change --> $("#"+boxnum).fadeOut('600'); to $("#"+boxnum).fadeIn('600'); in the handlehover() function

Comment: Yup, that works. Now for me to go through it and make sense of it all! Thanks for your help. Maybe there is one more thing you wouldnt mind looking at? The first box fades in twice when the page is loaded. If I take out $('.box #1').fadeIn(300); from the document ready function, it fixes the problem but it takes a few seconds for the first box to fade in. Any way to get it to fade in right when the page loads?

Comment: Once I use that code, should I have this code in the doc ready function?  $('.box #1').fadeIn(300); or just the startSlider()? If I dont have the fadeIn code in the doc ready it wont start the fade in. If I do have the fadIn in the doc ready, it fades in the first box and just sits there. Do you want me to upload it so you can see it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54417/discussion-between-eyal-barta-and-chipe).